# Hadoop job that writes output to HBase

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I am new to Hadoop and Hbase.

I was trying to make a small proof-of-concept Hadoop map reduce job that reads the data from HDFS and stores the output in Hbase.
The Hadoop version that I use is 2.7.1 and the Hbase version is 1.2.5.

I did the setup as presented in this tutorial [1].

Here is the pseudocode from the map reduce code [2].

Here are the logs from syslog [3], stderr [4] and console [5].

The problem is that I am unable to contact Hbase from the Hadoop job and the job gets stuck.

How should I correctly setup HbaseConfiguration ?
I couldn't find any example online that worked and it's hard for a beginner to debug the issue.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you,
Evelina

[1]
http://www.bogotobogo.com/Hadoop/BigData_hadoop_HBase_Pseudo_Distributed.php

[2]`Code`
https://pastebin.com/hUDAMMes

[3]`Syslog`
https://pastebin.com/XxmWAUTf

[4]`Stderr logs`
https://pastebin.com/fYUYw4Cv

[5]`Console logs`
https://pastebin.com/YJ1hERDe

Comment: Does HBase work well? Can you make a query to it via HBase shell? Check that ZooKeeper runs on 2181 port. And check your hostnames bindings. For example, check that all HBase settings use localhost as hostname (not 127.0.0.1 or FQDN).

Comment: Yes, I can create tables and insert data into them from hbase shell

Comment: in your logs mapper jumps from 0% to 100% very quickly. it is suspicious so possibly the problem is there. you can try to replace reducer writes from HBase to hdfs and see what happens